# imagepng under a Windows 2012 R2 Server

Tags: php, windows, image, converters

So the Situation is, that I have to automatically convert .jpg-files to .png-files, when a User uploads via POST.

The problem is: I just can't save the converted Image-Object I created with PHP... I'm running a Windows 2012 R2 Server, with Apache 2.4 and PHP 5.5.38.

According to the PHP-Manual I just need to give the function a path to a file:

```
$input = 'test.jpg';
$output = 'test.png';
$inputfile = imagecreatefromjpeg(realpath($input));
imagepng($inputfile,$output,9);
```

The output path can be an existing or non-existing file, right?
For the directory wherein the code is executed, the windows permissions are set to Full Access for everyone - so the problem shouldn't be there...

I'm pretty sure, it's just a dumb mistake I oversee :D
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind guys, just saw the right answer in the PHP manual comments...

> Blockquote
>   Be careful when using a variable for the file name.
>   PHP behavior with $filename differs when switching to PHP5.4 : PHP5.3 will use $filename='' the same way as $filename=NULL (e.g. no warning)